# Fourth order differential equation

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, partial-differential-equations

I have this physics mathematical problem : (see link in comment)

$$EI \frac{∂^4u}{∂x^4}= f \,\,\,\,\,\,\,\,\,\,\,\,\,\,\,\,\,\,\,\,\,\,\,\,\,\,\,\,\,\,\,(1)$$

The boundary conditions are:  $\,\,\frac{∂^2u}{∂x^2} = 0\,\,$   and $\,\,\,EI\frac{∂^3u}{∂x^3}=±F$

where $E$  is Young’s modulus, $I$ is second moment of area, $f$ is force per unit
length applied to the beam and $F$ is the force applied to the edges and the $±$ applies the the left and right edges.

The upper load placed on the chip is modelled as two point forces while the
loads exerted by the pins of the chip are modelled as (localised) Hookean springs
as shown in figure [$1$](in the link). Thus the equations become:

$EI\frac{∂^4u}{∂x^4} = −F \,[δ(x − B) + δ(x + B)] \,− \,k_2\,u(0)\, δ(x)\,\,\,\,\,\,\,\,\,\,\,\,\,\,\,\,\,\,\,\,\,\,(2)$

with boundary conditions :

$EI\frac{∂^3u}{∂x^3} = -k_1\,u(−A)\,\,\,\,\,,\,\,\,\,\,\,\,\, x = −A \,\,\,\,\,\,\,\,\,\,\,\,(3)$

$EI\frac{∂^3u}{∂x^3} = k_1\,u(A)\,\,\,\,\,\,,\,\,\,\,\,\,\, x = A \,\,\,\,\,\,\,\,\,\,\,\,(4)$

$\frac{∂^2u}{∂x^2} = 0\,\,\,\,\,\,\,,\,\,\,\,\, x = ±A \,\,\,\,\,\,\,\,\,\,\,(5)$

Given the displacement the tensile strain $\ebselen_{xx}$ can be calculated from the equation
$\ebselen_{xx}=\frac{h}{2} \frac{∂^2u}{∂x^2} \,\,\,\,\,\,\,\,\,\,\,\, (6)$

where $h$ is the height of the chip.

Show that calculating the displacements can be reduced to the problem of
solving a set of linear equations.

could you help please

---

Trying to answer:

$x$ axis:$\,\,\,\,\,\,$
$-A$_***_*____***$-B$****_*____***$0$****_*__*_****$B$****_*__*_***_$A$

$\,\,\,\,\,\,\,\,\,\,\,\,\,\,\,I\,\,\,\,\,\,\,\,\,\,\,\,\,\,\,\,\,\,\,\,\,\,\,\,\,\, II\,\,\,\,\,\,\,\,\,\,\,\,\,\,\,\,\,\,\,\, III \,\,\,\,\,\,\,\,\,\,\,\,\,\,\,\,\,\,\,\,IV$

- In area $I$ , $II$ , $III$ and $IV$ equation $(2)$ become ZERO: $EI\frac{∂^4u}{∂x^4} =0$
  solving this equation we get a linear equation system:

$$
\left\{ 
\begin{array}{c}
u_I=a_1x^3+a_2x^2+a_3x+a_4 \\ 
u_{II}=b_1x^3+b_2x^2+b_3x+b_4 \\ 
u_{III}=c_1x^3+c_2x^2+c_3x+c_4 \\
u_{IV}=d_1x^3+d_2x^2+d_3x+d_4
\end{array}
\right. 
$$
which has $16$ unknowns ($a$'s,$b$'s,$c$'s and $d$'s)

Comment: http://www.4shared.com/file/rdVHwO6j/strains_in_silicon_chip.html

Comment: Just some $\LaTeX$ notes, `\begin{equation} \end{equation}` will give your equations numbers, no need to write them yourself after lots of spaces. However, when in need of space, try \quad, \qquad, \qqquad, etc.

Comment: @BennettGardiner thank.. do u know how to write (ebselen)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$\newcommand{\angles}[1]{\left\langle #1 \right\rangle}%
 \newcommand{\braces}[1]{\left\lbrace #1 \right\rbrace}%
 \newcommand{\bracks}[1]{\left\lbrack #1 \right\rbrack}%
 \newcommand{\dd}{{\rm d}}%
 \newcommand{\ds}[1]{\displaystyle{#1}}%
 \newcommand{\equalby}[1]{{#1 \atop {= \atop \vphantom{\huge A}}}}%
 \newcommand{\expo}[1]{\,{\rm e}^{#1}\,}%
 \newcommand{\ic}{{\rm i}}%
 \newcommand{\imp}{\Longrightarrow}%
 \newcommand{\pars}[1]{\left( #1 \right)}%
 \newcommand{\partiald}[3][]{\frac{\partial^{#1} #2}{\partial #3^{#1}}}%
 \newcommand{\pp}{{\cal P}}%
 \newcommand{\sgn}{\,{\rm sgn}}%
 \newcommand{\ul}[1]{\underline{#1}}%
 \newcommand{\verts}[1]{\left\vert #1 \right\vert}%
 \newcommand{\yy}{\Longleftrightarrow}$

Let's $\ds{EI \equiv {1 \over \beta}}$. We understoot that $-A < -B < B < A$ where $A >0 $ and $B > 0$.

Then,
\begin{align}
\partiald[3]{{\rm u}\pars{x}}{x}
&=
-\beta k_{1}{\rm u}\pars{-A}
+
\beta\int_{-A}^{x}\braces{%
-F\bracks{\delta\pars{x' - B} + \delta\pars{x' + B}}
-
k_{2}{\rm u}\pars{0}\delta\pars{x'}}\,\dd x'
\\[3mm]&=
-\beta k_{1}{\rm u}\pars{-A}
-
\beta F\Theta\pars{x - B}
-
\beta F\Theta\pars{x + B}
-
k_{2}{\rm u}\pars{0}\Theta\pars{x}
\tag{1}
\end{align}
Since
$\ds{%
\left.
\partiald[3]{{\rm u}\pars{x}}{x}\right\vert_{x = A}
=
\beta k_{1}{\rm u}\pars{A}}$, we get the condition
$$
\beta k_{1}\bracks{{\rm u}\pars{-A} + {\rm u}\pars{A}}
=
-2\beta F - k_{2}{\rm u}\pars{0}
$$

From $\pars{1}$:
\begin{align}
\partiald[2]{{\rm u}\pars{x}}{x}
&=
-\beta k_{1}{\rm u}\pars{-A}\pars{x + A}
\\[3mm]&+
\int_{-A}^{x}\bracks{%
-
\beta F\Theta\pars{x' - B}
-
\beta F\Theta\pars{x' + B}
-
k_{2}{\rm u}\pars{0}\Theta\pars{x'}}\,\dd x'
\tag{2}
\end{align}

I hope the OP can take it from here. Just repeat the above procedures.

Comment: @Fayz You're welcome.

Comment: If δ(x) is Dirac Delta function.. what happen to(1) and (2) ?

Comment: I used the boundary conditions and also I intgrate equation (2) around -B and B, and that led me to find 12 of the unknown .... now what I should do .. I am really stock , please help.